# What is my motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

How can I know the model of the motherboard of my computer ?
I can not install any operating system for the moment on this computer to see the motherboard.
I opened the case but I can not see it.
My computer is Poweredge 2850 (yes, a server)

Comment: Dell motherboards are custom made, any model number would be unique to them.  What is the reason you need the info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would grab the Service Tag from the back of the machine and see what Dell lists as the original hardware installed in your PE.  It will show you part numbers that you can use to find more details on the individual components.

Comment: I read 6cfbv1j but Google does not mention it at all.

Comment: The service tag is unique to your machine, so Google won't have any information. Service tags should be look up on [Dell's Support website](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/6CFBV1J/maintain).

Comment: Go to dell.com and then the support link.  Pick your hardware model and where it asks for the service tag put the number in.  It will show you details of what was originally in the box.